# wufoo cross-domain settings?

Tags: jquery, iframe, wufoo

is there a way to turn off the cross-domain restrictions for wufoo so i can adjust the form fields from the parent of the wufoo iframe using jquery?

Comment: In case using Wordpress you can use this plugin https://github.com/alexandru-burca/wordpress-wufoo-custom-integration 

Otherwise use the Advanced Sharing Methods. More info here https://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/kb/Share#ctbcs

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're using the Wufoo "Embed Form Code" option which adds an iframe to your page.

You should use their "Full Page Form Code" option instead. -- No iframe. Instead, you're embedding the entire form within *your* web page. You can then use jquery to modify it. Remember that the form's submit url will be the Wufoo server.

[Docs](http://wufoo.com/docs/code-manager/#ctbcs)

Comment: The full page form code still uses an iframe, which makes it impossible to modify it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the code, edit and use it according to your needs.

On http://www.goldmore.com i am using wufoo, I use the same method. Just download the code provide for developers and edit it according to your needs...